# German analogue for "to run the program"

Tags: translation, english-to-german

So how would I normally say in German "I run this program" or "I launch this program" (on a computer). 
Dict.cc gives me "ausführen" and "laufen lassen" for "to run a program". Both sound quite difficult to pronounce. Is there an easier (colloqial) variant? Intuitively I would probably say "Ich ranne" or "Ich lasse los" or "Ich lasse auf"? Does it make sense?

Comment: What is your criterion for a difficult pronunciation? Most Germans find the English *th* sounds (\þ\ and \ð\) difficult to pronounce; Icelanders probably don’t.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft particulary I have problem with "laufen", how exactly I dont know, it is about rythm and tongue movements.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may not be a fan of »laufen«, but it would suit the purpose when it comes to computer programs:

> Ich lass’ das Programm laufen. *(I let the program run.)*

While “run” also describes an actually *running* program (at runtime you might say), the question is more about *starting* a program. With “launch” being a cognate for “start”, you probably would say:

> Ich starte das Programm. *(I start the program.)*

Neither of „Ich ranne“ *(I ran?)*, „Ich lasse los“ *(I let go)* and „Ich lasse auf“ *(I let on?)* makes sense regarding starting computer programs. Perhaps you can make friends with »Programm starten«, because if there are no errors, *starting* a program also means *running* it afterwards.

Comment: +1, although I *really* agree that OP should let go of his dislike for *laufen*

Comment: I didn't say I dislike the word. It just comes hard to say the whole sentence, but the reason is, yes this particular word. So you mean there is no jargon or some americanism for it?

Comment: @MikhailV: I’m a programmer and I don’t know of any. Colloquially, you say something along the lines of „Start’ einfach mal“ *(just start it)* or „Lass’ mal laufen“ *(let it run)* or „Führ’s mal aus“ *(execute it)*. The latter would also be a choide: **Ich führe das Programm aus**. By the way, »mal« is another perfect German filler word :-)

Comment: Thanks. And how is about "anlassen"? Lass es an? Sounds good but I am not sure if I ever heard such phrase.

Comment: Actually, with an artistic license, it would be semantically valid, but I think nobody would say that when it’s about computer programs. „Anlassen“ is related to engines, ignitions, etc.: „Ich lasse den Motor an“ *(I start the engine)*. Anyway, it was a nice idea, since [„anlassen“](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/anlassen) has quite some various distinct meanings.